# The meaning of "takes two to know"

Tags: phrases, idioms, proverbs

I know lyrics meaning is not a kind of a thing *English SE* is supposed to specialize in, but before looking for possible figurative meanings of the song excerpt that I put below I just want to reassure the phrase in bold is not a rare idiom or something.

There is a song by *Pink Floyd* - *Arnold Layne*. It has the following lines:

> Oh, Arnold Layne
>   It's not the same, **takes two to know**
>   Two to know, two to know
>   Why can't you see?

What does *(it) takes two to know* mean? Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is an idiomatic expression:

***[It takes two](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/it-takes-two)*** :

> If you say it takes two (or it takes two to tango), you mean that a situation or argument involves two people and they are both therefore responsible for it.
>
> - *Divorce is never the fault of one partner; it takes two.*

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Arnold Layne is a song about a Transvestite. Collecting women's clothes from the wash line suits him fine as he tried them on, distorted view in the mirror thinking he's a girl, yet see-through baby blue is a boy. It's not the same, a boy can't be a girl: ***it takes two to know*** *that there is a difference between a boy and a girl*, why can't you see?  (The song was banned on some English radio stations at its debut.)

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought that it was a bit more existential than that, i.e. that something is not real unless it's experienced by more than just you?